# Android bluetooth continously search not working?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have written the following code and want my bluetooth continously working, and is there any proper way so that my startdiscovery should be scan until my program in running?

```
          mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

      System.out.println("flow is here");
      // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
      final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
           if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

                System.out.println("Print in IF");
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());               
                //System.out.println(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);

                //info = mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getItem(x).toString();
                System.out.println("Found :\t"+device.getAddress()+"\tName :"+device.getName());

            }
            else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                    System.out.prinlnt("Else BOdy ");
                  mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
               }    
            }
```

Even System.out.println("Else BOdy") is not showing at all...

```
  int delay = 10000; // delay for 1 sec. 
  int period = 15000; // repeat every 10 sec. 
  Timer timer = new Timer(); 
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { 
          public void run() 
          { 
              displayData();  // display the data
          }
        private void displayData() {
            System.out.println("Veer Suthar is calling method after 10 seconds");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        } 
      }, delay, period);
```

This is what simply I have done, so it is called, and

```
if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
```

This method didn't work with me.

Comment: Can you add line with `registerReceiver` method or manifest `<receiver />` tag?